# AltBeacon : How can I get Advertising Flags (such as, BR/EDR) using AltBeacon Lib?

Tags: java, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon

Using Altbeacon lib, I can see the beacons that I am looking for.
@override
public void didEnterRegion(Region region) { ...}

But I also need to read AD Flags such as following, for example:
02 # Number of bytes that follow in first AD structure
01 # Flags AD type
1A # Flags value 0x1A = 000011010
bit 0 (OFF) LE Limited Discoverable Mode
bit 1 (ON) LE General Discoverable Mode
bit 2 (OFF) BR/EDR Not Supported
bit 3 (ON) Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (controller)
bit 4 (ON) Simultaneous LE and BR/EDR to Same Device Capable (Host)

Is there an API in Altbeacon lib to read the Flags?

Thanks,
Yong

Answer (score 1):

The flag data you describe is part of the BLE advertisement, but it is in a different part of the advertisement than the main AD type used for AltBeacon, iBeacon or Eddystone so the library is designed to ignore flag data.  Making the library parse this would require changes to the library itself.

As an alternative, you may wish to use raw Android scanning APIs so you can get to the flags.

Comment: Thank you very much David.  So, I could still use AltBeacon for scanning beacons, and only use Android APIs to get flags, right?  Thanks.